# How to make bootstrap navbar scale according to child element height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a fixed navbar on my website. The problem I have right now is whenever I increase the height of the logo, the logo goes outside parent navbar. I'm wanting to change that behavior so that navbar increases its height to adapt to new children height so that logo stays contained.

```css
.logo {
  max-height: 75px;
  padding: 1%;
  padding-top:2.35%;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0px !important;
}

.navbar-brand .logo{
    display:inline !important;
}
.navabar-custom{
    background: black !important;
    /*opacity:0.8;*/
}

.navabar-custom a{
    color:white !important;
}

.icon-bar{
background:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navabar-custom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="" class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/SEGA_logo.png">
                   
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="triggermockup">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="triggermockup">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="triggermockup">Services</a>
                        
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.navbar-brand` (parent of .logo) has fixed height of 50px. Just set it to auto

```css
.logo {
  max-height: 75px;
  padding: 1%;
  padding-top:2.35%;
}
.navbar-brand {
    padding: 0px !important;
    height: auto !important; /******* add this *******/
}

.navbar-brand .logo{
    /*display:inline !important;*/
    /* this is not needed */
}
.navabar-custom{
    background: black !important;
    /*opacity:0.8;*/
}

.navabar-custom a{
    color:white !important;
}

.icon-bar{
background:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navabar-custom" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="" class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                <img class="logo" alt="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/SEGA_logo.png">
                   
                </a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="triggermockup">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="" class="triggermockup">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="" class="triggermockup">Services</a>
                        
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>
```